# Are two different solutions possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Forgive me for not being able to articulate this very well.

Suppose I have an expression in $n$ variables $x_i$ such as

$$X = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_ix_i$$

Suppose for some values of $x_i$, the expression $X = 0$.

Now suppose I have some other set of constants $b_i$ where $b_i \ne a_i$  for all $i$ and where $b_i$ is not a multiple of $a_i$, is it possible for

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n b_ix_i = 0$$

The $x_i$ are the same in both cases, just the constants are varying.

Assume $x_i, b_i, a_i$ are non-zero real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x_1=1$, $x_2=-1$, $a_1=a_2=1$, and $b_1=b_2=\pi$. Then $b_i$ is not a multiple of $a_i$ for $i=1,2$ and
$$
a_1x_1+a_2x_2=b_1x_1+b_2x_2=0.
$$

Comment: I need to refine this question. Otherwise we can always take $n-1$ different constants for $b_1,...b_{n-1}$ and solve for $b_n$. Let me think more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think of the $x$s the $a$s and the $b$s as vectors, then you're saying $x$ is orthogonal to $a$ and to $b$ where $a$ and $b$ are not multiples. This is possible so long as $n\geq3$.